# Fixed position elements flicker while scrolling in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I have two elements that I've used `position: fixed;` on. They are fixed to the top-right of the page. I haven't seen what they look like in IE but Safari, Chrome and Firefox all look fine while scrolling. In Opera the elements flicker a bit as they're being redrawn. I should note that I'm testing this on Mac OS X. I searched around and found similar issues for an earlier version of Firefox. The fix then was to use `overflow: auto;` on the elements. I gave that a shot and it didn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas? It's not really a killer issue but it's definitely annoying. The site in question is [robertratleph.com](http://robertratleph.com/).

Comment: Dont see the flickering in IE9, FF4, GG11, AF5 and Opera11 when I scroll?

Comment: Maybe it's potentially only a Mac thing? What OS are you using?

Comment: Yeah I guess So. I am on Windows 7. Sorry Mate

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the info. That narrows it down a bit.

Comment: This probably depends on the preformance of the computer

Comment: Would it be performance related if it displays fine if every browser other than Opera? I've tried it on a MacBook Pro and a MacBook Air. I suppose I can try it on a more powerful machine but do you really think I'd need a Mac Pro to get Opera to not flicker while scrolling a fixed position element?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on MAC OS 10.7 with Safari. I added

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to the element being positioned fixed and it did the trick.

So adding:

```
-o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to the fixed element might do the job.

Comment: This works in Safari because 3D-transformed elements are rendered by GPU in Webkit; other elements aren't (oh god, these *"trigger hardware acceleration"* hacks remind me of that `zoom:1` days). However, in Opera, 3D transforms and hardware acceleration have nothing in common (they aren't supported currently), so this will probably have no effect at all.